# Identificar desenho em caracter - Canvas (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, drawing

Já consigo desenhar na tela usando um `DrawingView`, como mostro no exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma biblioteca para identificar o desenho e verificar se ele é um caracter, e se possível, dar uma porcentagem de semelhança.

Basicamente, o que eu quero é:

Desenhar um

## A

identificar essa letra no código, e dizer o quanto % de semelhança com a letra o desenho tem.

Conhecem alguma biblioteca que faz algo semelhante? Se já fizeram algo parecido, podem me dar uma luz? Googleei um monte, mas não cheguei a algo que me norteasse...

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/840623/Android-Character-Recognition

Comment: https://github.com/TrekDev/Xamarin.Android.OpenCV

Comment: https://shamsutdinov.net/2015/07/01/tesseract-orc-xamarin-part-1/